# Pure Python library to generate Identicons?

Tags: python, identicon

Does anyone know of a FOSS Python lib for generating [Identicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon)? I've looked, but so far I haven't had much luck.

Comment: It doesn't look that difficult to port one of the FOSS options on that page to Python. I know it's not the answer you want, but I couldn't find a Python one either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found two implementations:
http://coderepos.org/share/browser/lang/python/misc/identicon.py
http://code.google.com/p/visicon/

Comment: The first link is my preferred choice

Comment: I ditched the first one after it generated too many obvious swastikas.  Not culturally appropriate for my use-case.  The second one seems to have less of a propensity for that.

Comment: It seems both links are dead. I created a small utility that does this (the most lightweight pure python 3 implementation I've seen so far):

https://gist.github.com/Syncrossus/51e259d1adcf99b4f68737a602efeae6